# Nested TypeScript object with variable keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a JavaScript method that automatically imports JSON Schemas depending on directory structure. This means that I have a file located at `/path/to/my/file.json`, which is then loaded in `schemas.path.to.my.file`.

I use the following TypeScript definition to use my code in TypeScript, but to no avail. It keeps giving me errors about `no index signature`, even though, there seems to be one.

```js
import jsonschema = require("jsonschema");

interface NestedSchemas {
    [key: string]: NestedSchemas | jsonschema.Schema;
}

interface MySchemas {
    validator: jsonschema.Validator;
    initialized: boolean;
    walk: Promise<NestedSchemas>;
    schemas: NestedSchemas;
}

declare var _: MySchemas;
export = _;
```

When I then try to use my code, I see the following pop up by my linter:

[image]

The points of interest are the fact that it first shows `Schema` and then `NestedSchemas` (while defined the other way around in the interface), and that it doesn't try to resolve it anyway, since it's a string key.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the issue like this:
This gives the warning:

```
interface NestedSchemas {
    [key: string]: NestedSchemas | string;
}
const themas: NestedSchemas = {};
themas['0.1'].foo.bar.baz
```

while this don't:

```
interface NestedSchemas {
    [key: string]: NestedSchemas;
}
const themas: NestedSchemas = {};
themas['0.1'].foo.bar.baz
```

This is because typescript doesn't know if `themas['0.1']` will be of type `NestedSchemas` or `string`.

- You can circumvent that by casting:

`(((themas['0.1'] as NestedSchemas).foo as NestedSchemas).bar as NestedSchemas).baz`

(I admit, not very elegant)

- Or you may use a User-Defined Type Guards

You should read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html for details about it.

Comment: But how do I, in this case, define a "leaf" of my tree?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Do your mean this: `((((themas['0.1'] as NestedSchemas).foo as NestedSchemas).bar as NestedSchemas).baz as string)`